# Mysql query to sum a quantity from another table and under its group name if needed

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

[image: items table]

[image: Groups table]

I am trying to get this result

[image: Result table]

Im having trouble with this query, the quantities seem t0o large, this is what i have and its wrong. I want the items-title and group to concat if they are in the same row, and the qtys to be summed up. Thank you.

```
SELECT g.`groupname`, SUM(i.`qty`) as qty 
FROM `items` AS i 
INNER JOIN `groups` AS g 
WHERE i.`groupid` = g.`groupid` OR i.`rownum` > 0 
GROUP BY g.`rownum`
```

Edit:

This may help if i've not explained correctly

[image: Further results example]

Comment: Can there be multiple items with the same rownum? If so, which one is concatenated with the group name?

Comment: You need a full outer join, since you have groups with no matching `items.rownum`, and you have `items.rownum` with no matching groups. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: there can be multiple items with the same rownum, they are to be concat in the items output, like in rownum 1 'GROUP1 EA'

If items are in a group, they wont also be in a rownum of their own, but will be joined into the groups rownum

Comment: For the output, i want to show items and also groups on the same row. The groups contain the sum of the items quantities for that group, if that makes sense

Comment: now im wondering if i should of just made the items groupid the groupname and removed the group table altogether, this seems far simpler at the minute

Comment: But what if one of the items with `rownum=1` has `Title = EA`, and the other has `Title = XY`. What would be in the result, `GROUP1 EA XY`?

Comment: if XY in items had rownum=1, then yes. it is not in a group and would join in the result rownum 1. So 'GROUP1 EA XY', GROUP1 being the collective of BA, BB, BC. It doesnt show them, but uses their quantities.

Answer (score 0):

Split this into two subqueries. One gets all the groups and their corresponding items using a left join. The other gets the items that have no corresponding group. Then combine them with `UNION`.

```
SELECT g1.id, CONCAT_WS(' ', g1.groupname, g2.titles) AS groupname, g1.qty + IFNULL(g2.qty, 0) AS qty
FROM (
    SELECT g.id, g.groupname, SUM(qty) AS qty
    FROM groups AS g
    JOIN items AS i ON g.id = i.groupid
    GROUP BY i.id
) AS g1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT rownum, GROUP_CONCAT(title SEPARATOR ' ') AS titles, SUM(qty) AS qty
    FROM items
    WHERE rownum IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY rownum
) AS g2 ON g1.id = g2.rownum

UNION ALL

SELECT i.id, i.title, SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON g.id = i.groupid
WHERE g.id IS NULL AND i.rownum IS NULL
GROUP BY i.id
```

I haven't tested this. If it doesn't work and you'd like me to debug it, either create a db-fiddle or post the sample data as text so I can copy and paste it.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try later on today

Comment: ive set a db fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gFXY36bxXDWr9ytrzKdmrL/1

ive tried the code and also tried to make it work but i dont understand the error

Comment: I forgot `GROUP BY` in the last part of the query.

Comment: I fixed that, but the results aren't correct. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gFXY36bxXDWr9ytrzKdmrL/2 I don't have time to debug it right now, sorry.

Comment: no worries, ive tried my own version, whilst i get the qty's rightm the rownum and names are wrong

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vTgpiaxuyiYi1FkNrPgjzw/4

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the exact solution, I can work with this inside my web page...

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/viFL7xnknyZodpchPHtBqp/3

```
SELECT g.rownum, groupname AS name, IFNULL(sum(qty), 0) AS qty, g.groupid
FROM groups AS g
LEFT JOIN items AS i ON g.groupid = i.groupid
WHERE (g.groupid = i.groupid AND i.rownum = 0) 
OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM items AS i2 WHERE i2.groupid = g.groupid) AND g.rownum > 0)

GROUP BY g.rownum

UNION ALL

SELECT rownum, title AS name, qty, groupid
FROM items
WHERE rownum > 0 

ORDER BY rownum
```

**Close Solution**
[image: monitor data]